# Looking for an open source visualization library that will allow dynamic changes to the graph/tree in Java?

Tags: java, graph, open-source, data-visualization

I'm looking for a library that will allow me to construct a Tree and dynamically generate the branches/leaves of this tree at run time based on which branch the user selects.

Basically, it's similar to this prefuse example: http://prefuse.org/gallery/treeview/ except that the data isn't predifined in a an XML file. Rather the data is generated behind the scenes in my code based on the user's selection.

Is there such a library for this task?

Comment: Is this for a web based application? Does it need to be in Java?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is possible in prefuse. They just use graphml for entering data in that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html), [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/), [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/) or the alternatives on [this list](http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Math/Combinatorics/Software/Graph_Drawing/).